# How can I implement two plots on figure with canvas (matplotlib)?

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, plot

I would like implement two canvas plot in one window. I need on_running(x,y,z). X-Axe remains the same but I have still one plot with data z (y-axe) and data x(x-axe). How can I do it ?

```
def on_launch(self):
        #Set up plot
        self.figure, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.lines, = self.ax.plot([],[], 'o')
        #Autoscale on unknown axis and known lims on the other
        self.ax.set_autoscaley_on(True)
        self.ax.set_xlim(self.min_x, self.max_x)
        #Other stuff
        self.ax.grid()

    def on_running(self, xdata, ydata):
        #Update data (with the new _and_ the old points)
        self.lines.set_xdata(xdata)
        self.lines.set_ydata(ydata)
        #Need both of these in order to rescale
        self.ax.relim()
        self.ax.autoscale_view()
        #We need to draw *and* flush
        self.figure.canvas.draw()
        self.figure.canvas.flush_events()
```

Comment: yes, i do that with matplotlib.

Comment: have you tried using `self.ax.twinx()` to duplucate the x-axis?

Comment: i do that now with `(ax1,ax2)=plt.subplots(nrows,ncols)`